# Replace entire table row (including <tr></tr>) using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I've looked at other examples here, but they seem to be replacing the contents of a `<tr>` and not the entire row including the `<tr>`.

```
<table>
    <tr style="display:block">
        <td id="someid">Test</td>
        <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The following code seems to only replace the innerHTML of the `<tr>`. I need to replace everything, including the `<tr>` so that the row will collapse. Can anyone confirm that this code does or does not completely replace the row:

```
var newtr = "<tr style='display:none'><td id='someid'></td><td></td></tr>"
$("td#someid").parent().html(newtr);
```

The reason why I don't think the entire `<tr>` is being replaced is because the row doesn't collapse - though I have tested the HTML outside of JQuery and it works fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're almost there, just use the jQuery [`replaceWith`<sup>[jQuery docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function:

```
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

Comment: Wow, looks like this is the answer. I changed my code and it works better. Previously I was able to change the row about 32 times and all of the rows would disappear. I knew something was wrong. This fixed that. But my rows still aren't collapsing. Maybe this part is a CSS question, but this has been tested to work in the same HTML page as this script. Is there anything else I need to do on the JQuery end of things? Btw, thank you for all these answers!

Comment: @rwkiii If you need help with collapsing rows, you should ask a new question about that. All this does is replace a table row.

Answer (score 3):

The proper function is [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to replace the object, not its contents:

```
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use replaceWith method of jquery to replace the element.

```
$('#someid').parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the HTML technique as opposed to switching out elements, try this:

You are correct in saying that this will not replace the tr element.
.html("...") replaces the inner HTML of the element (the tr in this case).
Use the JavaScript outerHTML to achieve this: `$("td#someid").parent().get(0).outerHTML = newtr;`

Comment: FF 11.0+ Chrome 0.2+ IE 4.0+ Opera 7+ Safari 1.3+ supports outer HTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML). JQuery 1.2+ supports replaceWith method.

Answer (score 1):

See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/QXmTN/

**Jquery**

```
$("td#someid").parent().replaceWith(newtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/hELdz/)

```
var newtr = "<tr style='display:none'><td id='someid'></td><td></td></tr>";

$("td#someid").parent().parent().html(newtr);
```

Comment: This will over write existing html, if more rows exist.